# Sphinx reindex RT index

Tags: real-time, sphinx, rt

I have sphinx RT index, but i forgot add morphology when start insert records :(
Can i rebuild RT index without lost data? My config:

```
index track {
    type = rt
    path = /var/...
    other options...
}

searchd {
    listen = 127.0.0.1:9306:mysql41
    workers = threads
    other options...
}
```

I want add `morphology = stemenru` to index section, but command indexer --all --rotate has not results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to delete the index and start again.

Can't change morphology after the index has been created (because it changes how words are stored)

... `indexer` plays no role in RT indexes. RT indexes are entirely managed by `searchd`.